# Cannot run another ajax while long polling?

Tags: php, ajax, apache, long-polling

I'm trying to make a simple chat app on web, using long polling & php.

Mainly I have 2 ajax functions on the client,
1. update : to update the chat messages.
2. send : to send message the user enters.
The update function do a long polling, which is to wait until for 10 seconds or until new message is available.
The send function writes to a database.

My problem is, while the update function is running (long polling), the send function cannot run. And only after the update function has finished running, then the send function runs. Is this an expected behaviour or there is something wrong with my code?

If u want to see the web u can access it here : http://tedhost.awardspace.us
And if u're lazy to sign up u can use username dummy0 and password 123456

Here is the code..Sorry if my code is messy..
The ajax code : http://tedhost.awardspace.us/ajax.js

update_chat.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$filename = "wew.xt";
$user = $_SESSION["user"];
$last = $_SESSION["lmsgtime"];

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $lama = 0;
    $mulai = time();
    do {
        $fin = fopen($filename, "r");
        $current = 0;
        fscanf($fin, "%d", $current);
        fclose($fin);
        usleep(10000);
        $akhir = time();
    } while($current <= $last && $akhir - $mulai <= 10);
}
include "con.php";
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chats WHERE time > '$last' ORDER BY time ASC";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
/*
$lama = 0;
while (mysql_num_rows($res) <= 0 && $lama <= 10000000) {
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    usleep(500);
    $lama += 500;
}
*/
if (!$res)
    die("error");
$out = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $out = $out . "<div id=";
    if ($row["user"] == $user)
        $out = $out . "\"chatme\"";
    else if ($row["user"] == "sys")
        $out = $out . "\"chatsystem\"";
    else
        $out = $out . "\"chatother\"";
    $out = $out . ">";
    $out = $out . date("(h:i:s) ", $row["time"]);
    $out = $out . $row["user"];
    $out = $out . ": " . stripslashes($row["data"]);
    $out = $out . "</div>";
    $last = $row["time"];
}
$_SESSION["lmsgtime"] = $last;
echo $out;
?>
```

send.php

```
<?php
$time = time();
session_start();
include "con.php";
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["msg"]);
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["user"]);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$sql = "INSERT INTO chats VALUES ('$time', '$user', '$data')";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$res)
    die("err");
else
    echo "ok";
$lho = fopen("wew.xt", "w");
fprintf($lho, "%d\n", $time);
fclose($lho);
?>
```

Comment: is this the case on all browsers?

Comment: working on all browser is preferred, but not necessary. I'm doing this for learning purpose..

Comment: oh I think  I misunderstood ur question.. I've tried it on Chrome and Firefox, and it gives the same result. Not sure about other browsers..

Comment: I am srry I dnt hv much idea abt php

Comment: FYI you should look at web sockets for this app.. will be much better idea that using ajax and long polling. its an HTML5 spec

Comment: well, currently I'm focusing on learning php & ajax..I'll try looking at HTML5 some time later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the default session handler then only one script can have the session open at a time, as only one thing can write to a session file at a time otherwise corruption may occur.

It is possible that you can get around this problem by calling session_write_close as soon as possible in your scripts.  In the case of scripts that only read session data you should be able to call it straight after session_start.  In the case of scripts that make changes to the session, you'll have to call it immediately after the last change to the session you make.

While using session_write_close means that any subsequent changes you make to $_SESSION won't be saved, the $_SESSION array will still be accessible and contain the values last loaded from the session.

http://www.php.net/session_write_close has the relevant information.